# How to format confusionMatrix caret package

Tags: r, r-caret, confusion-matrix

Using the `confusionMatrix()` function from the caret package in R, how do you format your output vertically?

My current output is as follows:

```
$positive
[1] "spam"

$table
          Reference
Prediction  ham spam
      ham  1201   30
      spam    6  153

$overall
      Accuracy          Kappa  AccuracyLower  AccuracyUpper   AccuracyNull AccuracyPValue 
  9.741007e-01   8.800535e-01   9.643235e-01   9.817960e-01   8.683453e-01   5.647960e-44 
 McnemarPValue 
  1.264185e-04 

$byClass
         Sensitivity          Specificity       Pos Pred Value       Neg Pred Value 
           0.8360656            0.9950290            0.9622642            0.9756296 
           Precision               Recall                   F1           Prevalence 
           0.9622642            0.8360656            0.8947368            0.1316547 
      Detection Rate Detection Prevalence    Balanced Accuracy 
           0.1100719            0.1143885            0.9155473 

$mode
[1] "sens_spec"
```

I would like something like:

```
Accuracy:
95% CI
No Information Rate:
P-Value [Acc > NIR]:

Kappa:
Mcnemar's Test P-Value:

Sensitivity:
Specificity:
Pos Pred Value:
Neg Pred Value:
Prevalence:
Detection Rate:
Detection Prevalence:
Balanced Accuracy:
```

Comment: if you want complete control over the print format, you could just access the elements manually, i.e. `confusionMatrix()$byClass`

Comment: which command did you use to create this output? i generally get a vertically aligned by default.

Comment: I cleared the session, re-ran the code, and got the output I was looking for the second time. i'm not sure what i did, but it works now. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
t(confusionMatrix()$byClass)
```

and this:

```
confusionMatrix()$overall
```

Depending on the number of classes of you data you can rbind them or not

Comment: thank you! this works great. instead of clearing my session and re running my code, i'll implement your approach